# one page design

Tags: ajax

What if use just one html page with blocks inside,
like following

```
<div id="page1" style="display:block">...</div>

<div id="page2" style="display:none">...</div>

<div id="page3" style="display:none">...</div>
```

Active block has style="display:block" others "display:none",
when block becomes active "display:block" previous goes "display:none".

AJAX server communication, for instance

```
$.post("json", { "name": $("#name").val(), "sex": $("#sex").val() },
function(data) { console.log("server responded", data); });
```

What are disadvantages of this approach?

Comment: What do you do if the user is using NoScript for Firefox?

Comment: Or, you know, NoScript for any browser (why just firefox, is that one special or something?).

Comment: html5 is a future, no javascript - no modern mobile web. May be fallbacks to support very basic functionality.

Answer (score 1):

this is fast and dynamic but this approach lacks of no bookmarking facility, user can't save a particular link because the data is dynamic, also it is not search engine friendly, another disadvantage is history button back and forward will not work.

Answer (score 0):

There are no disadvantages to using pure AJAX. In fact, in a lot of ways, its advantageous.

If you don't plan for it correctly you can have some issues. For example, you're used to having CSS effect 1 page at a time, but with pure AJAX, the CSS will affect every single page.

Also, all things become slightly harder. Linking to another page becomes harder, as you have to use JavaScript.

Lastly, your APP will now REQUIRE JavaScript, so I'd have a decent fallback.

Answer (score 0):

This approach is used in some mobile Web frameworks, such as jQuery Mobile, and is intended to make a Web application feel more native. This is more Web 2.0 than traditional websites or web applications where each page transition involves a trip to the server.

I'm sure you know the advantages already, so let's move on to the disadvantages.

**Slightly Greater Initial Latency:**

The main disadvantage of this approach is that it will take slightly longer to load the page content due to the fact that you're getting all of the HTML from the server in one single trip. Thus, the initial load time may involve more latency than in a traditional Web 1.0 application. However, with just a few pages, in my experience, the latency is not significant enough for it to be a problem.

**Loss of Back Button - More Complexity in Maintaining History:**

Another potential disadvantage is that, as a developer, you'll need to approach the development of your site differently. Because you're transitioning pages by hiding one DIV block and unhiding another, you'll lose native back button functionality. This can be mitigated by using the hash in the URL to record the history of page transitions. You'd then need to register an event to watch the hash and reload old content as the user navigates backwards. You'd also need to change the state of JavaScript objects and variables to refect the old state, which may add complexity to your app. There are of course API's and libraries to make this easier to implement and help ensure that you write good, maintainable code.

**More Stateful Scope Involves Rethinking Approach and Possible Learning Curve:**

Lastly, you'll need to remember that the scope of each page doesn't reset after each transition. While this could actually be an advantage in that your app is more stateful, you'll need to untrain yourself in the way of thinking that each page loaded will cause all of the JavaScript variables and data you've set to be cleared out.

**Summary:**

My suggestion, if you're going to go this route, is to use a library. Don't reinvent the wheel unless you have a good reason to. Libraries, like jQuery mobile, help ensure that there is good fallback for older browsers, and some even make sure that your site will still load using Web 1.0 techniques for cases where JavaScript is disabled.